# Azure Functions [Node.js]: context.bindingData not containing my route params as documentation suggests

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm currenty building a function that should retrieve 2 route params (first required, second optional), but I'm facing some issues despite following their Documentation.

Specifically I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript#customize-the-http-endpoint) bit of instructions, but unfortunately it wont work as expected.

In my function.json I have the following piece of code:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "name": "req",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [ "get" ],
      "route": "MyFunction/{courseId:alpha}/{locale:alpha?}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

The instructions tells that I can access these two params on the `context.bindingData`, but it doesn't appear. The only way I (at this moment) can access the information, is by splitting the path (which is present on `context.bindingData.path`).
I really don't like that solution though, especially when the documentation tells another way to do it.

Here what's inside `context.bindingData`:

```
{
    "invocationId": "1067e7e5-f85f-481c-8605-645cf78dcb25",
    "path": "MyFunction/windscreen/en",
    "query": {
        
    },
    "headers": {
        "cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,br",
        "accept-Language": "da-DK,da;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,la;q=0.6,nb;q=0.5",
        "host": "localhost",
        "user-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
        "upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "content-Length": "0",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"92\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"92\"",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "x-Forwarded-For": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "sys": {
        "methodName": "MyFunction",
        "utcNow": "2021-08-05T13:56:43.800Z",
        "randGuid": "[Censored]"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to the latest Azure Functions Core Tools from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases) and see if you are still seeing this behavior.

I used version 3.0.3477 and can not reproduce it. For reference, the biding information used is similar to what you have, as shown below:

```
 {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [ "get" ],
      "route": "MyFunc/{firstParam:alpha}/{optionalParam:alpha?}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

URL used: /api/MyFunc/FirstValue/OptionalValue

context.bindingData: [screenshot of context.bindingData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIa8r.png)